# Skip row if file does not exist in a directory

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on a macro that will add an image into a cell if the cell contains an image name (image1.png) that is in a specified directory. So if it finds "image1.png" in the directory it adds the image to the cell and moves to the next row. Here is the code thus far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertPicss()
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim fPath, fDir As String

fDir = "Macintosh HD:Users:Connor:Desktop:siteimages:"
For Each cell In ws.[A1:A12]
    fPath = fDir & cell.Value
    With ws.Pictures.Insert(fPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .Width = 48
            .Height = 48
        End With
        .PrintObject = True
        .Top = cell.Top
        .Left = cell.Left
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

The issue it stops at a row that does not have an image name that is located in the directory it is looking at.

Is there a way to skip the row if it doesn't have that image in the corresponding directory and make it to the end of all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, use `Dir` to check if a file/folder exists.

Below works for Windows, but not sure about Mac.

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertPicss()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim fPath, fDir As String

    fDir = "Macintosh HD:Users:Connor:Desktop:siteimages:"
    For Each cell In ws.[A1:A12]
        fPath = fDir & cell.Value
        If Dir(fPath) = cell.Value Then ' If Not Dir(fPath) = "" Then
            With ws.Pictures.Insert(fPath)
                With .ShapeRange
                    .Width = 48
                    .Height = 48
                End With
                .PrintObject = True
                .Top = cell.Top
                .Left = cell.Left
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I'm using a Mac but I'll give it a go.